# UIButton touch up inside event hook up in coding phase?

Tags: events, ios4, uibutton

I create a `UIButton` in coding phase and never use Interface Builder so how can I call `touch up inside` event to hook up with any method in coding phase??

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**Swift 3:**

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewControllerName.BtnPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: Thank you saadnib it works. BtnPressed: ":" is optional If there is no parameter we don't use this.Because I take runtime error if I use ":" without parameter :)